# jQuery display marker on tapped position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show marker on my specific div on tapped position.
I did this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(e){         
         $("#myimg").offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
         })
})
```

JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/

Issue is on every tap I want to show the marker (by keeping the old one also), on every next click last marker hide I want to show on every clicked position.

Cheers!
Ajay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `clone` the element, then append the new one to the document:

```
.myimg {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```js
$("#test").click(function (e) {
    $(".myimg").first().clone().offset({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY
    }).appendTo('body');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/szCAL/4/)

Note that I changed the `id` to a `class` as you will now have multiple copies of this element in the page.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(e){         
         $("body").append("<img class='myimg' width='10' src='http://www.nystce.nesinc.com/images/tests_circle.gif' height='10' />");
      $('.myimg').last().offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY});
  })
})
```